# how to create virtual bacnet devices and implementing python library

Tags: bacnet

im very new to the bacnet protocol.I'm working in python , so i need help regarding python library called BAC0.
i already read BAC0 documentation on the internet and tried their examples but im not able to get the curect output. 
please help me with some examples like how to create virtual bacnet devices and how to perform read and write operation on which using python programing.Thanks in advance.

i tried examples mentioned in the BAC0 documents

```
my_obj_list = [('file', 1),
             ('analogInput', 2),
             ('analogInput', 3),
             ('analogInput', 5),
             ('analogInput', 4),
             ('analogInput', 0),
             ('analogInput', 1)]

bacnet = BAC0.connect(ip='192.168.42.226/24')
mycontroller = BAC0.device('2:5',5,bacnet, object_list = my_obj_list)
print(mycontroller)
mycontroller.points
mycontroller['point_name']
```

````
2019-07-22 15:49:31,169 - WARNING | Offline: provide database name to load stored data.
2019-07-22 15:49:31,169 - WARNING | Offline: provide database name to load stored data.
2019-07-22 15:49:31,169 - WARNING | Offline: provide database name to load stored data.
2019-07-22 15:49:31,169 - WARNING | Offline: provide database name to load stored data.
2019-07-22 15:49:31,169 - WARNING | Offline: provide database name to load stored data.

also im getting an error :
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\BAC0\core\devices\Device.py", line 688, in connect
    self.properties.address, self.properties.device_id
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\BAC0\core\io\Read.py", line 184, in read
    "APDU Abort Reason : {}".format(reason)
BAC0.core.io.IOExceptions.NoResponseFromController: APDU Abort Reason : noResponse.```
````

Answer (score 2):

```
mycontroller = BAC0.device('2:5',5,bacnet, object_list = my_obj_list)
```

You must have a BACnet controller on your network with those parameters to read them. The code you are running is not creating a virtual BACnet network. It is made to connect to real device.

If you want to create a virtual device, you can get inspiration here : 
https://github.com/ChristianTremblay/BAC0/blob/master/tests/conftest.py

as in the test suite, I create virtual devices that talk to each other.